# Databinding issue with data not updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, data-binding

I have a datagrid that I am having to add columns to in the code behind because I do not know what the columns will be until runtime. ResultsGrid is the datagrid.

```
ResultsGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Header = columnName,
                Binding = new Binding("results[" + columnName + "]"),
                CanUserSort = true,
                Visibility = buildingFieldList.Single(x => x.FieldName == columnName).Visibility
            });
```

buildingFieldList has a lists of all the columns that will be used. It is an ObservableCollection that contains objects of my custom type DBField. I have stripped out the irrelivant stuff and pasted the class below:

```
public class DBField : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private bool _Enabled;
private Visibility _Visibility;

public bool Enabled 
{
    get { return _Enabled; }
    set
    {
        _Enabled = value;

        if (_Enabled)
            _Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        else
            _Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        OnPropertyChanged("Visibility");
        OnPropertyChanged("Enabled");
    }
}

public Visibility Visibility
{
    get { return _Visibility; }
    set
    {
        _Visibility = value;

        if (_Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
            _Enabled = true;
        else
            _Enabled = false;

        OnPropertyChanged("Enabled");
        OnPropertyChanged("Visibility");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
}
```

I have a checkbox that when clicked, modifies the enabled property and as such also modifies _Visibility and calls the OnPropertyChanged. What I expect to happen is that column now has the visibility collapsed. However, it is not changing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was a little more tricky than I thought. Clemens was going down the right path for me, but I did not see that silverlight had a `DataGridColumn.VisibilityProperty`. I found that others were having issues because this property was not exposed as well. To get around this, they extended from the column and made their own class. I did as well with the following:

```
public class ExtendedDataGridTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
public ExtendedDataGridTextColumn() : base() { }

public Visibility ColumnVisibility
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ColumnVisibilityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ColumnVisibilityProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnVisibilityProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ColumnVisibility",
    typeof(Visibility),
    typeof(ExtendedDataGridTextColumn),
    new PropertyMetadata(ColumnVisibilityChanged));

private static void ColumnVisibilityChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ExtendedDataGridTextColumn column = sender as ExtendedDataGridTextColumn;
    if (args.NewValue != args.OldValue)
    {
        column.Visibility = (Visibility)args.NewValue;
    }
}
}
```

Then I added these custom columns to my data grid:

```
Binding testBind = new Binding();
testBind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
testBind.Source = buildingFieldList.Single(x => x.FieldName == columnName);
testBind.Path = new PropertyPath("Visibility");

ExtendedDataGridTextColumn temp = new ExtendedDataGridTextColumn()
    {
    Header = columnName,
    Binding = new Binding("results[" + columnName + "]"),
    CanUserSort = true
    };

BindingOperations.SetBinding(temp, ExtendedDataGridTextColumn.ColumnVisibilityProperty, testBind);

ResultsGrid.Columns.Add(temp);
```

Thanks to Clemens for helping me along. I hope this will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have the visibility property on the column set to a static value, not a binding.

```
Visibility = buildingFieldList.Single(x => x.FieldName == columnName).Visibility
```

You would need to bind the Visibility property to the visibility property on your object.

Comment: Could you demonstrate that? I tried to do that as well but could not figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the DataGridTextColumn's `Visibility` to be updated when `DBField.Visibility` changes, you would have to use a Binding:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("Visibility");
binding.Source = buildingFieldList.Single(x => x.FieldName == columnName);

DataGridTextColumn column = 
    new DataGridTextColumn()    
    {    
        Header = columnName,    
        Binding = new Binding("results[" + columnName + "]"),    
        CanUserSort = true,    
    };

BindingOperations.SetBinding(column, DataGridColumn.VisibilityProperty, binding);
```

And it would perhaps be a good idea, to remove the `DBField.Visibility` entirely and instead bind directly to the `Enabled` property and use [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx):

```
Binding binding = new Binding("Enabled");
binding.Source = buildingFieldList.Single(x => x.FieldName == columnName);
binding.Converter = new BooleanToVisibiltyConverter();
```

Comment: I do not see that `DataGridColumn` has `VisibilityProperty`.

Comment: Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.visibilityproperty.aspx) for WPF. If your platform is Silverlight: i don't know if `DataGridColumn.Visibility` is altogether a dependency property in Silverlight. You could try `UIElement.VisibilityProperty` in `SetBinding`.

Comment: I have added an answer to this question to my solution I have working. Thanks for the help.